# "cat *" (read all output) Crashes Terminal and Gedit

Tags: command-line, bash, gedit, cat

This command:

```
cat * > cat_all.txt
```

successfully results in the file **cat_all.txt**, as expected. However, the text file will not open in Gedit. The behavior is mostly freezing, screen-darkening, `xkill`ing type of junk. I have not yet tried any other editor, it's just kind of a fun and strange mystery right now.

I have a suspicion that it could be something to do with the characters or encoding (I'm not very learned on that end) because running the command

```
cat cat_all.txt
```

successfully results in the file being read in the terminal; however, the output is pretty funky and I cannot discern much of it. In addition, new lines on the terminal start over at the top, and overwrite (sometimes without erasing) the existing nonsense on the screen. One time, the terminal froze and crashed.

Now, the command

```
cat [anything else] > newfile.txt
```

gives back the file I want with no problems, no matter the filesize- and this **cat_all.txt** file claims to only be ~493kb! I understand that "cat-ing" something like an `apt-get` is useful and is also direct (text) input from the terminal to itself. But then, so is `cat *`. Or is it literally attempting to translate every file in the current directory into text?

What thing have I summoned? Or is this a simple issue? Weird, nonetheless.

Comment: Forgive any improper formatting or rambling, it's probably been over a year since I've been active. Cheers!

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Why using cat on binary files messed up the terminal and how?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, that is helpful and at the same time, what a world to get into. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Your expectation with the `cat * > cat_all.txt` command is incorrect, this command is _not_ always intended to finish in finite time resulting in a reasonably sized file. If `cat_all.txt` already exists when you launch this command, and the overall contents of the alphabetically preceding files is larger than a certain size (`cat`'s input and output buffer lengths combined), then the `cat` command will endlessly append the contents of this file to itself.

Comment: `cat` does not translate the files in any way, it just appends the bytes. Presumably one or more files aren't text only. It's utterly irrelevant how you construct `cat_all.txt`, especially that we know nothing about the contents of all (`*`) your files. It's a bug in Gedit as well as Terminal (do you mean GNOME Terminal?) if they crash on opening/cat'ing this certain file. If you can reliably reproduce this, you should report to the developers.